# Where is the action.class in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for create new user?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I installed  sfDoctrineGuardUser for Symfony 1.4.11, but I can't find the action.class, where register user. I find only **class sfGuardCreateUserTask** :

```
  protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {
    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);

    $user = new sfGuardUser();
    $user->setEmailAddress($arguments['email_address']);
    $user->setUsername($arguments['username']);
    $user->setPassword($arguments['password']);
    $user->setFirstName($arguments['first_name']);
    $user->setLastName($arguments['last_name']);
    $user->setIsActive(true);
    $user->setIsSuperAdmin($options['is-super-admin']);
    $user->save();

    $this->logSection('guard', sprintf('Create user "%s"', $arguments['username']));
  }
```

but this isn't this...

I can't find anywhere for example **$user->setFirstName($arguments['first_name']);** and modified to:

```
$user->setFirstName($arguments['first_name'] . '@');
```

Where is the action.class in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin for create new user?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you don't need that action (or to customize it) in order to create new users. Just create a custom action that generates your registration form and handles the post:

```
$user = new sfGuardUser();
$user-> // manipulate however you like
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cache\frontend\prod\modules\autoSfGuardUser\actions
```

or something similar

if this is what you're looking for, don't rewrite it in there!!
Instead, copy the action to your normal sfGuard module and edit it there

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is already published by the symfony team :

- http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-simple-registration-with-sfdoctrineguardplugin
- for further information : http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-customizing-sfdoctrineguardplugin